How fairing halves are closed to each other for smooth separation? Are they use locking bolts or else?
I have seen a clip of closing two halves of RUAG fairing. At the end, both halves met in "Tongue and Groove" type joint with matching holes.it seems now both halves of the fairing will lock thru bolts. If they lock fairing thru bolts than how it will separate? Are these bolts contains explosive or what design they have?
I'm adding a pictures for more  understanding.



Not familiar enough to post as an answer; The separation plane is not the same plane / joint as the bolted joint. It is a thinner section that is slightly offset with a separate mechanism.

On which rocket? Different rockets use different mechanisms

Is separation plane offset from the axi symmetric plane of the fairing?
